# How to animate display table to none or zero height?

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I am trying to animate a header, when the class `collapseTest` is added to the header. I came up with the following: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/atuyLtL0/1/ Thanks to @Hackerman for helping me out with the working one.

What I want is when the class `collapseTest` is added to the header, the white div with the class `.top` should disappear. Since I use `display: table` instead of `display: block`, I can't hide the div including the content with the CSS rule `display: none`. The content does not disappear.

I use the following animation, that is working for `display: block`, but not for `table`.

```
@-webkit-keyframes pushDown {
    0% {
        height: 50%;
        display: table;
    }
    100% {
        height: 0;
        display: none;
    }
}
```

I call this one on the div with the class `top`:

```
#header.collapse .top {
    -webkit-animation: pushDown 2s forwards linear;
}
```

But this isn't working as expected. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong, why the div with the class top isn't animating to hidden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply styles to `#header .top` and its children.  Something like this:

```
#header.collapseTest .top {
    height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    margin-top: -20px;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out 0s;
    transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out 0s;
}

#header.collapseTest .top * {
    opacity: 0;
    height: 0;    
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out 0s;
    transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out 0s;
}
```

Parsing the CSS in your fiddle was difficult, as it appears there is a lot more than is needed for an example of the problem.  Nevertheless, I created the following fiddle with my code changes:  http://jsfiddle.net/pbukcne4/

Comment: Thank you for the working example. Do you also know a solution to transition the hamburger menu in my example  and the other part seamless with each other?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you are asking.  Hamburger menu?